# Error: expected expression on line using #defined constant

Tags: objective-c, macros, compiler-errors

I'm doing this

```
if ([resourceCompletionReward objectAtIndex:experienceD] != 0) {
```

But Xcode is giving me an error:

> Expected expression

I've defined `experienceD` as

```
#define experienceD 0;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The semicolon shouldn't be there.

```
#define experienceD 0
```

will compile just fine.

Also it's a good practice to name constants with an UPPER_CASE_NOTATION like this.

For completeness I will add that Apple suggests (from the [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-1001783))

> In general, don’t use the #define preprocessor command to create constants. For integer constants, use enumerations, and for floating point constants use the const qualifier

and also

> You can use const to create an integer constant if the constant is unrelated to other constants; otherwise, use enumeration

So in your specific case it would be better to define your constant as

```
static const int ExperienceD = 0;
```

Comment: [Constants in Objective-C are usually named using camel-case.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-1001783)

Comment: It's a different kind of constants, using the `const` keyword. Preprocessor macros are usually uppercase.

Comment: Take a look at the headers of Foundation or AppKit and you will find quite a few constants still defined by `#define` in camel-case.  Also, this particular constant would clearly be better defined using `const` instead of `#define`.

Comment: I agree on the second point (I already edited my post, if you see). On the naming convention for preprocessor macros, I think there are no explicit guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t use `#define` to define constants. All that `#define` does is text replacement, so in your case the compiler sees

```
if ([resourceCompletionReward objectAtIndex:0;] != 0) {
```

and complains about the `;` where it shouldn’t be.

This can be especially troublesome if you want to calculate your constant:

```
#define CONSTANT 1 + 2
int y = 2 * CONSTANT;
```

The compiler does simple text replacement so you get

```
int y = 2 * 1 + 2;
```

which is not really the expected value. To work around this you can remember to add parentheses around each #defined constant.

A better way to define constants is to use `const` variables:

```
static const int experienceD = 0;
```

If you define lots of constants with consecutive integer values you also can use an enum.

```
enum {
    experienceD = 0;
};
```